# Month and year number from date field (To Create a reference field) Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am looking to get the month number and the year when referening a date field

However, when trying to use Month() or Format () it doesnt allow me to use the Date field

I want to get the month number and year from the data column - which will allow me to create a reference of Year * 12 + month number

Any Suggestions ?

customer    due-date    Month Number    Year    Reference   Calculation
1001    28/02/2023  2   2023    24278   =(D2*12)+C2
1001    31/03/2023  3   2023    24279
1001    31/03/2022  3   2022    24267
1001    30/04/2022  4   2022    24268
1001    30/06/2022  6   2022    24270
1001    31/08/2022  8   2022    24272

Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpSnk.jpg)

Comment: It sounds like you might be trying to create a measure, but really want to be able to reference a particular row.  A calculated column might work better.  Do you have any error or code to share?

Answer (score 0):

- first check: is [due-date] column in date format? if so, then you can use formula as Month=month([due-date])

[image: see here column data type]

> However, when trying to use Month() or Format () it doesnt allow me to
> use the Date field

- then if column type cannot change. try formulas below:

Month=mid([due-date],4,2)

Year=right([due-date],4)

Year&Month=[Year]*12+[Month]